How do I fetch my Google FIT stats on web? Any api?
I'm looking to manage the data synced from my fitness watch, "Noise," to Google Fit. Currently, all my fitness statistics are displayed in the Google Fit app. I would like to disable these stats from appearing in my portfolio, but I'm unsure how to proceed.
If anyone has experience with this or can provide guidance, I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thank you!
I haven't tried anything.

I figured out and made a simple express server script that logs my data.
You can check out https://github.com/krushna06/Fitness-API
Feel free to contribute since I'm looking to make this better.
